# PHP Variable within Wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, accordion

I need to use a shortcode but insert the variables the customer enters into the shortcode.

I have tried to use the below:

```
echo do_shortcode('[su_accordion][su_spoiler title="What is your name and your position in       the company?"]'.the_field('whats_your_name_and_your_position_in_the_company').'[/su_spoiler][/su_accordion]');
```

However it just puts the echo'd text above the accordion shortcode http://prntscr.com/3zzfv9.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not clear on your comment "... insert the variables the customer enters into the shortcode"  When does the customer do that, on this page, or somewhere else on the website?  I'm assuming elsewhere, but thats not clear.  I'm assuming the_field(cat slug name?) is previously populated before this page is generated.  With those assumptions this short code looks fine.  Possible there are some coding style issues before / after this area of your program?  And note:  Why would you expose us to that horrible lightshot spam ad site when you could just as easily used the native stackoverflow tools?

Comment: The issue I assume is this: '.the_field('whats_your_name_and_your_position_in_the_company').'

Do I need to escape the apostrophes on 'whats_your_name_and_your_position_in_the_company' ?

Comment: hmm.. do_shortcode('..."..."..' . the_field('...') . '...' ) Looks absolutely okay to me.. I'm sure you've already tried the_field("..."), right?   I'm suspecting a miss somewhere else in the code?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77384/echo-do-shortcode-with-custom-field-not-working

Need to use get_field as opposed to the_field